# Can cargo.toml contain custom properties

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I've recently started with Rust and coming from a Node background I'm curious if the `cargo.toml` file for a project can be extended to include custom properties.

For example, in Node, some packages let you put configuration options in the `package.json` file (like babel):

```json
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [ ... ],
    "plugins": [ ... ],
  }
}
```

I've looked through the [manifest docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html) but I can't seem to find anything about custom properties.

For example, what if I had a CLI tool and it has a configurable option. Do I have to have the user make a config file just for this option or could I include in the `cargo.toml` like so:

```
[package]
name = "my_project"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"
# custom property
store: ["one", "two", "three"]

[dependencies]
```

Also, if this is a "sure, as long as you have `name` and `version` as required", is it something that should be avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rust equivalent would be Cargo [features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html). You can define features for a crate like this in the crate's `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "crate_with_features"
version = "1.0.0"
edition = "2018"

[features]
# default set of features
default = ["has_foo", "has_bar"]

# can use these for conditional compilation
has_foo = []
has_bar = []
```

And then if you had a `lib.rs` like this:

```rust
[cfg(feature = "has_foo")]
pub fn foo() {
    println!("foo");
}

[cfg(feature = "has_bar")]
pub fn bar() {
    println!("bar");
}
```

People would be able to select just which features of your crate they want. For example:

```
[package]
name = "other_project"

[dependencies]
crate_with_features = "1.0.0"
```

In the default case, `crate_with_features` would come with both `foo` and `bar` functions since the `default` feature requires both of them, but people could choose to only use one or the other by specifying:

```
[package]
name = "other_project"

[dependencies.crate_with_features]
version = "1.0.0"
# don't include default feature set
default-features = false
# cherry pick individual features
features = ["has_foo"]
```

In the above example `crate_with_features` would only be compiled with the `foo` function for that project.

The Rust Reference has a [page on conditional compilation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html) if you'd like to learn more about that specifically.