# Adding a custom value into a Cargo.toml file

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

### Background

I'm currently in the process of writing a crate that's bindings for a C library and I need the user to specify where the built library is. Previously, I've seen this handles by the [`llvm-sys`](https://crates.io/crates/llvm-sys) crate using environment variables. However, having used this a lot it can become quite cumbersome to have to write this every time I want to run a project.

### similar questions

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65766269/can-cargo-toml-contain-custom-properties) post that asked a similar thing, but seemed to only be able to use specified tags, so not able to specify a path.

### What I want to do

I would like to know if there's any way I can have a specific *custom* value in the Cargo.toml file. The idea being the crate I'm writing would require a specific value (I'll call it `example` here) that can take any string value. so when this crate were to be used in another project, that projects `Cargo.toml` file would be similar to this::

```
[package]
name = "some-other-project"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies.my_crate]
version = "0.1.0"
example = "something goes here"
```

This value would then be accessible by the crate I'm writing (the dependency in regards to the above manifest file) and usable in some way.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you want to accomplish.

Comment: So to be clear, you want users of your library crate to be able to specify some configuration value that's available to your library during compilation?

Comment: Yes. That's a very succint way of putting it thank you

Comment: I'd probably have them set an envvar (which they could do [via Cargo configuration](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#env)), and use the [`env!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.env.html) macro to access it.

Comment: Didn't know about setting evvars in the [env] section thanks!

Comment: To be clear, the Cargo configuration files are not the same as the crate's `Cargo.toml` manifest file; although Cargo will search from the current directory up to the root for a `.cargo/config.toml` so they can place one in their project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can set environment variables using a Cargo configration file](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#env) (`.cargo/config.toml`) then you can retrieve them in downstream crates by using e.g. [`env!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.env.html)/[`option_env!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.option_env.html)/build scripts.